# .NET Log Soap Request on Client

Tags: .net, web-services, logging, .net-2.0

I'm consuming a third party .NET WebService in my client application.  For debugging purposes I want to capture the SOAP requests that are being sent from my server.  How would I go about doing this?  This is being done on .NET 2.0 without the use of WCF or WSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's for debugging purposes I'd just configure the web request to use a proxy and send the entire request though fiddler (http://www.fiddlertool.com) then you can see exactly what's getting transmitted over the wire.

Comment: I tried about 6 different ways of doing this in code before giving up and trying fiddler. Had I read about it and seen that it supports encrypted traffic I would have started with it first.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a post about this a while ago titled "[Logging SOAP Messages in .NET](http://desalasworks.com/logging-soap-messages-in-net/)".

The easiest way is to **use the tools already provided with .NET**.

**1.** Extend the class **`SoapExtension`**.

**2.** override the method **`ProcessMessage`** to get a full output of  your Soap Request, then output this information to a text file or event log.

```
public class SoapMessageLogger : SoapExtension
{
  //…
  public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
  {
    switch(message.Stage)
    {
      case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
        LogResponse(message);
        break;
      case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
        LogResponse(message);
        break;
      // Do nothing on other states
      case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
      case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  //…
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options you can use. There are certainly some commercial tools for this (like SOAPScope), but if you're just looking to capture the raw contents of the requests/responses there are several tools out there besides Fiddler (that Walden mentioned already).

Personally, I've been a long time user of Simon Fell's [TcpTrace](http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/) and [YATT](http://www.pocketsoap.com/yatt/).

If you're interested in actually instrumenting the code so that it can do it on its own (say, by logging everything to a file or something), then you might want to look into implementing a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SoapExtension to log the Soap calls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [the Web Service, SOA and SOAP Testing Tool - soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) with good success in the past.

-Edoode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **wireshark** ? I'm always using it for capturing traffic of my applications.