# Web Service Request

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am building a web site that consumes an external web service. I have added the WSDL of the external service as reference to my site. How do I view the contents of the SOAP envelope that is sent as request when I call the web method in the external service?

I get an `XML Parse Exception` when I make the web service call. So I want to see the contents of the SOAP envelope that is being sent as request.

Comment: If you found the answer out yourself, please post an answer to this question and then mark your own reply as the answer. This keeps the "Unanswered"-category of questions less cluttered. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat similar question already here on SO: [.NET Log Soap Request on Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149851/-net-log-soap-request-on-client).

Tools that are suggested are:

- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)
- [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)